# When to use "nugatory"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Definition of [nugatory](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nugatory) given by the Oxford Dictionary:

> Of no value or importance

Short and simple. So it is basically the same as *useless*, right? If so, then why is there a need to use it? Why don't we just use *useless* directly? It seems that the existence of the word *nugatory* is ... nugatory. In my knowledge, there is no a single word that has an exactly meaning or nuance to another word. There must be a niche market of the word to exist.

So what is the niche market for *nugatory*?

Comment: You use *nugatory* when you're sick and tired of saying *inutilious*.

Comment: @DanBron what is *inutilious*? Google can't find it

Comment: It's a joke: "without utility".

Comment: I love 'inutilious', and will use it :)

Comment: follow up question: [Why does the word “nugatory” become nugatory?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/279280/80007)

Comment: It's actually a double meaning.  Consider "This candy bar is really nugatory!"

Comment: The niche market for "nugatory" is clearly those instances when you want to impress or confuse your interlocutor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nugatory is a quite formal word used mainly in  Law meaning 'not valid' or formal speech.

Example:

> - The clause excluding negroes and Chinese from the suffrage has never been repealed, although it has been ***rendered nugatory*** by the Fifteenth Amendment to the Federal Constitution.
> - We may be forced to conclude that the interest of the whole affair, so far as authentic history is concerned, ***is really nugatory*** and that the romantic imagination has created a mystery in a fact of no importance.

(sentence.yourdictionary.com)

[Nugatory](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/nugatory) ,   Vocabulary.com also  suggests  ***a jocular use*** of the term in current usage:

> - An adjective meaning “trifling, of no value,” nugatory comes from the Latin nugatorius “worthless, futile,” which in turn came from the also Latin nugatory — “jester, trifle.” It’s a word you probably don’t hear too often, but it’s a fun and descriptive one to use. Describe something with no force or importance as nugatory. "Whether this rug is red or green is nugatory to someone who is colorblind."

[Nugatory](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=nugatory)(adj.) (Etymonline)

> - "trifling, of no value," c. 1600, from Latin nugatorius "worthless, trifling, futile," from nugator "jester, trifler, braggart," from nugatus, past participle of nugari "to trifle, jest, play the fool," from nugæ "jokes, jests, trifles," of unknown origin.

- Its usage has been decreasing consistently in recent decades as shown in 
  [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nugatory&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnugatory%3B%2Cc0).

[image: image description]

Comment: +1 for jocular use. Catullus ironically called his poetry `nugae`

Answer (score 6):

Nugatory doesn't have the 100% same meaning of *useless*. It is rather closer to trifling as [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nugatory) defines.

> 1. of little or no consequence :  trifling, inconsequential
> 2. having no force :  inoperative

The congressional resolution has symbolic value only, as it relates to a matter governed by the states and is thus **nugatory**.

The book is entertaining, but its contributions to Shakespearean scholarship are **nugatory**.

I don't think you can use *useless* for the second example. There, it means  small or trifling, not useless.

Its origin is the Latin word nūgae which means trifles.

Comment: could the first definition be interpreted as *not much*?

Comment: @Ooker If it can be used to describe *value*, why not?